# How to connect mysql database and run queries with protractor?

Tags: mysql, protractor

I want to change the data in in database at the time of protractor run, any one please help me how to connect and run queries with protractor. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Guess you still need an ORM to execute the queries... We are using Mocha, in combination with chaiJs and sequelizejs (which is the ORM for running the database sql queryies, which we also use for the application itself).

Comment: Thanks @ErikVandeVen, in development we user Doctrine ORM, is it need to testing also?

Comment: Ow sorry, I was confused. Wrote yesterday a test for sequelize and they used their ORM inside their test to dump dummy data in a sequelize_test database as far as I remember. Just checked our tests, but we use our own created Restful API, to set update and delete records within our tests and front-end (in the back-end sequelize takes care of the rest). But I also checked Mocha and they seem to have possibilities to connect to the database, and protractor seems to have this possiblity as well: https://rafaelbattesti.wordpress.com/2014/08/06/protractor-how-to-connect-to-mysql-database/